Windows - RDP (host) error code 0x3, extended code 0x12
I have a headless Windows 10 setup (GT 1030, Intel Core i5, Z87M-PLUS) with RDP host turned on. After restart, the RDP host works and I am able to use RDP from different client machine flawlesly. However after some time (several days) it stops working and an error is displayed on client side when initiating the connection.

Same behavior for different independent clients. Other services on the server work as expected.
I have gone through the Event Log on the host machine and found out a log that may be related to this: "The device Microsoft Remote Display Adapter (location (unknown)) is offline due to a user-mode driver crash.  Windows will attempt to restart the device 5 more times.  Please contact the device manufacturer for more information about this problem."
I have tried to apply this workaround: "Disable Computer Configuration -> Administrator Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Session Host -> Remote Session Environment -> Use the hardware default graphics adapter for all Remote Desktop Services sessions", however it hasn't solved the issue.
I can see some other people are facing the same issue: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowserver/forum/all/black-screen-remote-desktop-error-code-0x3/15a46225-14f6-48d3-92cb-fd7a629886a2
What might be the problem?

Caused by faulty GPU. Not only RDP was affected, but even with display connected in this state, nothing was rendered.
